# Build a confidence interval

Tags: statistics, descriptive-statistics

I am studying descriptive statistic and I am trying to do this exercise but I am not getting.

A certain manufacturer guarantees that his machines produce only $5\%$ of defective parts. In order to verify the veracity of this statement, $1000$ pieces produced by a machine were analyzed, of which $40$ pieces had some type of defect. Build a $95\%$ confidence interval for the proportion of defective parts and discuss the manufacturer's claim.

Comment: What you tryed?

Comment: @Nabla I thought about how can I do this? My teacher said that the average is 40, standard deviation = 5% so 0.05, but why?

Comment: Look up the confidence interval for proportions.

Comment: @VagnerWentz The estimated proportion is $\hat p=0.04$. And the estimated standard deviation of p is $\frac{s}{\sqrt n}=\sqrt{\frac{0.04\cdot  0.96}{1000}}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\hat p=\frac{40}{1000}$, so a 95% confidence interval for the true population proportion is $\hat p\pm z*s.e.=\frac{40}{1000}\pm 1.96 \sqrt{\frac{\frac{40}{1000}\left(1-\frac{40}{1000}\right)}{1000}}=(0.02785432, 0.05214568)$. 5% is contained in this interval, so we believe the manufacturer's claim that 5% of his items are defective is reasonable.

Comment: You use the traditional Wald asymptotic CI, which should be be reasonably accurate for $n$ as large as $n = 1000.$ (+1)